# How did "excited for" come about?

Tags: grammar, idioms, language-change

I really don't like the phrase "excited for" which seems to have become very common in recent years, as in "I'm excited for the weekend...".  My sarcastic reply would be "I don't think the weekend cares or appreciates you being excited on its behalf".  Anyway, I'm aware I have to accept that language changes, even though here I think it's just bad grammar.

The question is ... are there any studies looking at how (the wrong use of) this phrase came about?

I have a theory based on absolutely nothing, that perhaps it came from Spanish where 'por' can be used in this sense, e.g. Google translates "excited about this weekend" to "emocionad(o/a) por este fin de semana".  Is it possible that this usage came via speakers of Spanish, perhaps in the US?

Comment: I can find many books with the phrase ["excited for the weekend"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22excited%20for%20the%20weekend%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018,cd_max:2018&lr=lang_en), so I don't think it is really a misuse. Also, there is [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=excited+for+the+weekend%2C+excited+about+the+weekend&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) which shows that both "about" and "for" are in common usage, so I would hesitate to call it "bad grammar"...

Comment: _Excited for_ seems to me to refer to one's excitement for the good fortune of another: _I'm excited for Harry, winning first place._ I'd use _excited about_ for a weekend I was going to spend.

Comment: Cambridge considers "Are you [**excited for**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/excited) your first Oscar nomination?" to be informal.

Comment: Couldn't 'excited for the weekend', in some of its occurrences, mean that the weekend was the period during which one felt the excitement, rather than the object of the excitement (e.g. 'I was excited for the weekend, but bored aftrewards')?

Comment: As the "sarcastic" reply shows clearly, I think this usage could be labelled  better as bad semantics, and even that is questionable ("_he went away for a while_": a new meaning is soon introduced or an idiom is soon coined). The very same question could be raised for the also recent and controversial "apreciates you being excited".  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appreciates+you+being%2Cappreciates+your+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: The Spanish thing is irrelevant. I'm excited about the party. I've excited for her; she won the race. This is all basic usage. I'm excited about the weekend; we should have a lot of fun. about=regarding the subject of

Comment: Note that this meaning of "for" is not unique to "excited". For example, if Romeo is crazy for Juliet, he is not crazy on her behalf. (If we were talking about Hamlet and Ophelia, though . . .)

Comment: "I'm crazy for her" is used, but "I'm crazy about her" is more common (as in "Mad about the Girl"). Even "I'm crazy over her" is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is an American English issue (possibly regional) which is catching om via Hollywood movies.

Ngram of "excited ***for*** the weekend, excited ***about*** the weekend" shows mixed results for AmE, but only "excited ***about*** the weekend" shows in BrE.

In other words, [the AmE query with "about" shows as a recent usage going back to the 1970s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=excited%20for%20the%20weekend%2Cexcited%20about%20the%20weekend&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3), while the version with "for" only dates back to the 1990s in US literature, [and not at all for BrE.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=excited%20for%20the%20weekend%2Cexcited%20about%20the%20weekend&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)

So I would say that this is a recent American usage that still sounds "wrong" for British speakers, but would be acceptable for American speakers.

Note that much new language  that originates in the New World eventually finds itself taken up as slang in the EU, whether we like it or not.

Cambridge considers the "excited for something" to be informal usage in BrE.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/excited

Comment: I'm excited for him; he won the prize. I'm excited about him. He's coming down this weekend. Those are just standard in any English? I don't like ngrams for this type of question.

Comment: And in your link, there's: Are you getting excited about your holiday? Who says that's slang? The whole utterance is typically British.

Comment: @hi Lambie///lovely to hear from you too. How are you? I know you travel a bit, and I was worried...

Comment: Ah, travel? I wish. I keep getting you mixed up with araucaria because you both use names that remind me of Brazilian words. :) Cascavel and Araucaria, a Brazilian pine tree.

Comment: Is racism possible when referring to trees and reptiles?

Comment: I would be hesitant to jump from the n-grams to the conclusion that this construction 'would be acceptable for American speakers' in general.  Obviously it is acceptable to those who use it, and the n-grams show that their number is not negligible, but that doesn't tell us anything about the speakers of American English who don't use it: we don't know how many of them abstain from using because it just doesn't fit their style, and how many perceive it as wrong, irritating, slangy, indicative of insufficient education, etc.

Comment: @jsw29 When language change happens, it's often the case that the previous generations consider it "wrong". But if it it catches on it becomes "correct" and they're old fuddy-duddies, pedants, etc.

Comment: @Barmar, I am well aware of all that; my point is that, without further investigation, the n-grams do not tell us how far the acceptability of this particular construction has spread at this point: is it only in the social groups X, Y, and Z, or only among the people younger than ___, or . . . ? I very much doubt that it is among the speakers of American English generally. And even if it were true that only 'old fuddy-duddies' object to it, that would need to be taken into account in deciding whether the construction is generally acceptable.

Comment: @jsw29 I think the general assumption when citing Ngram is that the acceptability of a phrase is directly correlated with its frequency. There may be exceptions, but it's probably a reasonable approximation.